# How do I inspect objects in Firefox Web Console using the keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, web-console

When I enter the name of an object in the command line of the Web Console of Firefox, it shows up as `[object Object]`.

I can then click on the object with the mouse to inspect it. Is there a way to do this using the keyboard, or to directly dump the object in expanded form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use `console.dir(object)`.

I am surprised that it is not mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Web_Console.

### Edited (2015-05-24):

Currently, there'a a entry for console.dir() on docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/console/dir

Answer (score 0):

There is now something better than this. Try:

```
inspect(object)
```